# Change underscore to hyphen in search tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-search

When creating a tag with an underscore, say `wm_activate`, the underscore is automatically modified to a hyphen: [wm-activate](/questions/tagged/wm-activate), which is by design.

Now, if you enter the tag `[wm_paint]` in the search criteria, then the underscore is deleted: `[wmpaint]` and [no results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wmpaint) are found.

Could the underscore in tags automatically be changed into hyphens, just as when creating tags with underscores, so it leads to the [wanted results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wm-paint)?

Comment: I think this is a bug report, not a feature request.

Comment: You have to purposefully hold shift to get the underscore on most keyboards.  I don't see a reason to support this erroneous behavior.  Users who manually search `[tag]` rather than `tag` should know enough not to do this, I would think, and searching `wm_paint` has valid results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting in the next build, when checking for tags (keep in mind this only happens in the top N, usually 40 or 80 on most sites) we'll replace `_` with `-`.  The `[a_b]` case we *won't* handle...since you're being very explicit about asking for a tag there.